# Use of undeclared type in Swift 3

Tags: ios, xml, swift3, swxmlhash

I have the following class to return a list of NOAA weather observation stations. I am using it to learn how to deal with XML. However, I am getting a "Use of undeclared type 'wxObservationStations'" as an error at func returnWxStation()  -> (wxObservationStations). I am using SWXMLHash to deserialize the XML, but I don't think that is my problem (though I am just learning, so it may be).

```
class WxObservationStations {

let wxObserStationsURL = URL(string: "http://w1.weather.gov/xml/current_obs/index.xml")

struct wxStation: XMLIndexerDeserializable {
    let stationName: String
    let stationState: String
    let latitude: Double
    let longitude: Double

    static func deserialize(_ node: XMLIndexer) throws -> wxStation {
        return try wxStation(
            stationName: node["station_name"].value(),
            stationState: node["state"].value(),
            latitude: node["latitude"].value(),
            longitude: node["longitude"].value()
        )
    }
}

public var wxObservationStations: [wxStation] = []


private func getStationNamesAndLocations(url: URL, completion:@escaping (XMLIndexer) -> ()) {

    Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON { response in
        //                print(response) // To check XML data in debug window.
        let wxStationList = SWXMLHash.parse(response.data!)
        print(wxStationList)
        completion(wxStationList)

    }
}

//The error is here:
func returnWxStation() -> (wxObservationStations) {
    getStationNamesAndLocations(url: wxObserStationsURL!, completion: { serverResponse in
        do {
            self.wxObservationStations = try serverResponse["wx_station_index"]["station"].value()

        } catch {

        }
    })
      return self.wxObservationStations
}
}
```

Any thoughts? The variable is declared in the class, and I would like to use it to send the data back to the requesting object. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `wxObservationStations` is not a type, so it doesn't make sense to say

```
func returnWxStation() -> (wxObservationStations) { ... }
```

You're returning `self.wxObservationStations`, which is of type `[wxStation]`. So the method declaration should be

```
func returnWxStation() -> [wxStation] { ... }
```

---

By the way, your life will be much easier if you stick with Cocoa naming conventions, namely types should start with upper case letters. So rather than the `wxStation` type, I'd suggest `WxStation`.

---

Your following method will not achieve what you want:

```
func returnWxStation() -> [wxStation] {
    getStationNamesAndLocations(url: wxObserStationsURL!, completion: { serverResponse in
        do {
            self.wxObservationStations = try serverResponse["wx_station_index"]["station"].value()
        } catch {

        }
    })

    return self.wxObservationStations
}
```

The method `getStationNamesAndLocations` runs asynchronously and your `self.wxObservationStations` will not be populated by the time that `returnWxStation` actually returns.

The entire purpose of the `getStationNamesAndLocations` method is to provide you a nice asynchronous method with completion handler. I would excise `returnWxStation` from your code entirely. Or do something like:

```
func returnWxStation(completionHandler: ([wxStation]?) -> Void) {
    getStationNamesAndLocations(url: wxObserStationsURL!) { serverResponse in
        do {
            let stations = try serverResponse["wx_station_index"]["station"].value()
            completionHandler(stations)
        } catch {
            completionHandler(nil)
        }
    }
}
```

And you'd use it like so:

```
returnWxStation() { stations in
    guard let stations = stations else {
        // handle error here
        return
    }

    // use `stations` here
}

// but not here
```

Comment: Thanks! I do try to stick with the conventions, but as I am learning I am unsure of whether things are types or objects at time. As to whether the code works, I suspected it wouldn't for that reason, but I am trying to get it to the point where it will build and run so I can work on it from there, so your additional answer is a great help.

Comment: @Rob, Excellent answer, except it looks like you made an editing error. The code in the returnWxStation function should not return `try serverResponse...`. That line should pass that expression to the completion handler.